# JClouds-Chef: Invalid value for cookbook_versions?

Tags: java, chef-infra, jclouds

I'm using the JClouds-Chef API to dynamically-create new Chef [Environments](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-chef/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jclouds/chef/domain/Environment.java) on the fly.  The main gist of my code:

```
Environment.builder()
    .name("${appName}_${envStr}")
    .description("A really cool app")
    .cookbookVersion("my_app", "0.2.0")
    .cookbookVersion("my_logs", "0.1.0")
    .attributes(buildAttributes(envStr))
    .build()
```

When this runs I get the following error:

```
[main] INFO com.myapp.ChefManager - org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: command: POST https://mychef01/environments HTTP/1.1 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request; content: [Invalid value '0.2.0' for cookbook_versions]
    at org.jclouds.chef.handlers.ChefErrorHandler.handleError(ChefErrorHandler.java:57)
    at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingErrorHandler.handleError(DelegatingErrorHandler.java:67)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.shouldContinue(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:180)
```

I found someone with a [similar issue](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup/issues/10) from last year, and it seems that this might have been a bug introduced between Chef 10 and Chef 11? If so, is there a hack or workaround to this from JClouds-Chef?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the constraint operator to the version strings? Something like:

```
Environment.builder()
    .name("${appName}_${envStr}")
    .description("A really cool app")
    .cookbookVersion("my_app", "= 0.2.0")
    .cookbookVersion("my_logs", "= 0.1.0")
    .attributes(buildAttributes(envStr))
    .build()
```

Comment: Yes @Ignasi Barrera - that was exactly it! Just curious: what was going on here (what was the root cause of the problem) and why did adding these constraints fix this?

Comment: It is just how the Chef Server expects the versions.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi Barrera, and is it something that was introduced in Chef 11 that wasn't there in Chef 10?